# Retrieve RNA sequencing data for human p53 colon cancer cell lines

Tags: sequence-analysis, rna

I want to download the next generation RNA sequencing data in different cell lines. I want the data (alongwith normal) for p53 wild type, p53 knock-out and p53 null cell lines (human colon cancer). From where do I download this data? In fastq format if possible.

Currently, I am going through SRA, to look for the datasets, using their search engine. But the process is extremely tedious.

Also can someone please hint about how to download the data from SRA, in case that's the only way to get data. I'm getting very confused.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Could you help us explaining if you could manage to download any dataset? Also, what kind of sequencing data do you want: single-cell RNa-seq, long read or bulk RNA-seq? Also if you could clarify if you have some preference for a programming language to automatize the process it would help too

Comment: Hello, What exactly you find tidious? If you search for "p53 AND "Homo sapiens"[orgn:__txid9606]" you get plenty of hits for NULL and WT. For example reads liked to [this](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sra?linkname=bioproject_sra_all&from_uid=350308) project. If you want fastq files, you can pull them from ftp server once you know IDs, here is an example: ftp://ftp.sra.ebi.ac.uk/vol1/fastq/SRR835/SRR835937/

Comment: Hello, thank you all for such an immediate response. Ilrs, I want RNA seq data obtained from p53 WT, NULL and KO colon cancer cell lines, without any other modifications in the cell. I'm not bothered about programming language for further analysis now. I am actually new to this, and I don't know if I am collecting the right kind of data or not.  Kamil, these are shPFKFB4 silenced. I want normal vs experiment data from same experiment if possible. I might be making very silly mistakes, I apologise for the same. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Downloading from ENA is simpler: https://www.ebi.ac.uk/ena

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to try difference resources, including ArrayExpress. 
A simple search at [ArrayExpress](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/arrayexpress/browse.html?keywords=p53&organism=Homo%20sapiens&exptype%5B%5D=&exptype%5B%5D=%22sequencing%20assay%22&array=&page=1&pagesize=500) returns multiple experiments which might be of your interest. Just a pointer, ArrayExpress is also synced with GEO.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Kamil on the downloading method.
Moreover, SRA will give you your file in the raw format which is usually a **Binary Alignment Map (BAM)** or **Sequence Alignment Map (SAM)** 
Download [SRA toolkit](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sra/docs/toolkitsoft/) available online, to convert your raw reads to fastq format. Follow the steps using command line. It is a very simple command to convert your SRA file to fastq which uses the *fastq-dump* command.

Further reading: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK158900/

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hello Pawan, my main concern here it to pinpoint the data I require from the database. I am not able to find the data I require. I'm aware about fastq-dump. Thank you for your efforts.

Comment: I understand! Since you had asked if it was possible to download in fastq format, i had answered accordingly. Cheers

Comment: Thanks. Actually, when I'm using fastq-dump, all I see upon execution of command is a bunch of .cache files.Also, as huge files in GB scale take time to download, I would like to know if there is a way where we can track the progress of download?

Comment: Can you specify the size of your file?

Comment: Last file I tried downloading  was roughly 12GB. Max download speed on my network is 550kbps.

Comment: Well, downloading at this speed will take over 6 hours.